# How do I set Securityonion/snort to not capture certain packets?

Tags: linux-networking, configuration, snort, pcap

After looking through my pcaps from Security onion I'd like to filter out a host (let's call it 192.168.4.4) and filter out some traffic (ports 80 & 443), current project is to look at other traffic not web related.

running tcpdump/windump I can do this simply tcpdump -w notwww.pcap not 192.168.4.4 not port 80 not port 443

But I cannot find documentation or a location to put this in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with bpf Berkley Packet Filter.
the config is located in your **/etc/nsm/$sensorname/bpf.conf**
I've not found a *really* good resource how to write them but for my requirements this worked

```
! host 192.168.4.4 && ! port 80 && ! port 443
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused by your question. When I have used a scheuled TCPDUMP, I have always just called it from the cronjob. I dont believe there is a config file to apply filters.

Also I believe you are missing your AND clauses in the above statement.

I believe your statement should look more like this:

```
tcpdump -vv not src 192.168.4.4 and not dst port 80 and not dst port 443 -w notwww.pcap
```

You could also use the OR clause to simplify your statement

```
tcpdump -vv not src 192.168.4.4 and not (dst port 80 or 443) -w notwww.pcap
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Snort/Security onion has it running as part of the "package"
That would be the easy way, but I'm trying to keep the changes in the Snort/Security onion configs.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I am not familiar with that specific package.... thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Neither was I until earlier today.  It's all about learning.